# async upload multiple files to google cloud storage bucket

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload multiple files to a Google Cloud Storage bucket using NodeJS. I want all files to be uploaded before continuing. I tried several approaches but I can't seem to get it right.

```
const jpegImages = await fs.readdir(jpegFolder);

console.log('start uploading');

await jpegImages.forEach(async fileName => {
    await bucket.upload(
        path.join(jpegFolder, fileName),
        {destination: fileName}
     ).then( () => {
         console.log(fileName + ' uploaded');
     })
})

console.log('finished uploading');
```

This gives me the following output, which is not what I expect. Why is the 'finished uploading' log not executed after uploading the files?

```
start uploading
finished uploading
image1.jpeg uploaded
image2.jpeg uploaded
image3.jpeg uploaded
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`async`/`await` doesn't work with `forEach` and other array methods.

If you don't need sequential uploading (files can be uploaded in parallel) you could create an array of Promises and use `Promise.all()` to execute them all at once.

```
const jpegImages = await fs.readdir(jpegFolder);

console.log('start uploading');

await Promise
    .all(jpegImages.map(fileName => {
        return bucket.upload(path.join(jpegFolder, fileName), {destination: fileName})
    }))
    .then(() => {
        console.log('All images uploaded')
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(`Error occured during images uploading: ${error}`);
    });

console.log('finished uploading');
```

Comment: Add error handling to the code and this would be a great answer.