# Upload multiple items to firebase storage bucket

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to create a form that when pressed creates a document on the firebase database. In this form there is a title, Description and an array of images to be displayed.

When I try to upload multiple items I get an error

> FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: The operation 'uploadBytes' cannot be performed on a root reference, create a non-root reference using child, such as .child('file.png'). (storage/invalid-root-operation)

Here is my code I'm trying.
Just to note i'm using sveltekit, but think the main problem im having is to do with firebase.

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage';

const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, setupImages);

const setupImageArray = new Uint8Array(setupImages);
await uploadBytes(storageRef, setupImageArray).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded an array!');
});
```

When running the submit I get the files saved into an array called SetupImages as seen here
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIlk3.png)

But also the error that i stated above. With the error showing up it stops anything uploading into the storage bucket

I've tried doing it with a single image and I've managed to get that working with this code

```
const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, listingImage.name);

await uploadBytes(storageRef, listingImage).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

But again, not sure on how the whole array of files works.

I've been looking over the Firebase docs but there isn't too much to go off of when it comes to arrays as I'm quite new to using firebase so I could be missing something simple.

From what I can tell from the firebase docs I'm to create a varible and pass in the array of files that i want to upload to the firebase storage. Then i use the firebase UploadBytes with the store reference and the array reference which then snapshots the data and sends that snapshotted data with the file names to the storage?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have to call uploadBytes once for each file to upload. There is no batch operation for multiple files.

Comment: In addition to @DougStevenson's suggestion, combine them under `Promise.all`, to keep them in parallel for quicker resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Doug commented, there is no operation to upload multiple files to Storage in one go. You'll need to loop over the array, and upload the files one by one.

As Hiren commented, you'll want to avoid using `await` on each individual call to `uploadBytes`. Instead gather all the promises returned by the calls to `uploadBytes` into an array, and then use `Promise.all` on that.

Also see:

- [async upload multiple files to google cloud storage bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095155/async-upload-multiple-files-to-google-cloud-storage-bucket)
- [How to upload multiple files to Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673499/how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-firebase)